# Find child of child which attribute code is equal to the parameter passed on the url - XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

On this dynamic website, 
The url looks something like this : departments/CHEM.html

CHEM is a parameter.

```
     <xsl:param name="dep" select="'CHEM'" />
```

a piece of the xml is below

```
<course acad_year="2012" cat_num="5085" offered="Y">
  <term term_pattern_code="1" fall_term="Y" spring_term="N">fall term</term>
  <department code="CHEM">
     <dept_long_name>Department of Chemistry and Chemical Biology</dept_long_name>
     <dept_short_name>Chemistry and Chemical Biology</dept_short_name>
  </department>
</course> ....
```

I am trying to get the dept_short_name to use on my H1 tag, but I have not been successful.So far I tried

```
<h2><xsl:value-of select="course/department/[code={@$dep}]"/></h2>
```

Any suggestions??? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="course/department[@code eq $dep]/dept_short_name"/>
```

**Remember**:

In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) use the `eq` operator for value comparissons -- it is more efficient than the general comparisson operator `=` which really, only, needs to be used when at least one of its operands is a sequence.

Comment: Thanks it does work, however it prints the dept_short_name multiple times, how do i print only 1, I tried adding a zero or one like the example below, but it did not work.
<xsl:value-of select="course/department[@code eq $dep][0]/dept_short_name"/>    Thanks again!

Comment: @Cristy, Use: `(course/department[@code eq $dep]/dept_short_name)[1]`, or use `distinct-values(course/department[@code eq $dep]/dept_short_name)`

Comment: Thanks distinct values made it for me!! now it looks like this and it only prints one 
<h2><xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(course/department[@code eq $dep]/dept_short_name)"/>  </h2>

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="course/department[@code=$dep]/dept_short_name/text()"/>
```

That says: find the department element (inside a course element) whose code attribute is the value of parameter "dep", then find the dept_short_name child element, then get the text inside that element.

You have to use the `@` to say that "code" is an attribute, but "dep" should not have it.  I think the `{}` notation is for use inside attributes of the non-XSLT elements of your stylesheet, so I wouldn't use it inside a `value-of` expression.