# Find a child which parameter is equal to a variable XSL

Tags: xslt

I need to get this:

```
<a href="departments/CHEM.html">Chemistry and Chemical Biology</a>
```

I tried using this code:

```
<a href="departments/{department/@code}.html">
```

But as a result I get `<a href="departments/.html">Chemistry and Chemical Biology</a>`

This is my xml

```
<fas_courses>
   <course acad_year="2012" cat_num="5085" offered="Y">
      <term term_pattern_code="1" fall_term="Y" spring_term="N">fall term</term>
      <department code="CHEM">
         <dept_long_name>Department of Chemistry and Chemical Biology</dept_long_name>
         <dept_short_name>Chemistry and Chemical Biology</dept_short_name>
      </department>
      <course_group code="CHEM">Chemistry</course_group>
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question's title implies there's some kind of variable involved, which I don't see in your question's body. Could you clarify this?

Comment: Or can this question be closed as a duplicate of [this other one of yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877533/find-child-of-child-which-attribute-code-is-equal-to-the-parameter-passed-on-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the full path to department as :

```
<a href="departments/{fas_courses/course/department/@code}.html">
```

If there are multiple nodes, you need to use indexing to get specific node or looping to get each individual node.